# memcpy in C++ doesn't copy u_int32_t to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, memcpy

I'm with a problem when using `memcpy` function.

I need to create an array of `unsigned char` with three parts: id, size of data array, data array. But I couldn't do nor the first part yet.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {    
    u_int32_t OID;
    unsigned char *serialized;
    
    OID = (u_int32_t)5;
    
    serialized = new unsigned char[sizeof(u_int32_t)];
    
    memcpy(serialized, &OID, sizeof(u_int32_t));
    
    std::cout << "After inserting OID: <" << serialized << ">\n";
    
    memcpy(serialized, "test", sizeof(u_int32_t));
    
    std::cout << "After inserting \'test\': <" << serialized << ">\n";

}
```

The output this code generates is:

```
    After inserting OID: <> 
    After inserting 'test': <test>
```

I can't understand why, in the first case, `memcpy` doesn't copy `OID` to `serialized` and in the second case it copies the string `test` correctly.

It would be great if you could help me.

Thank you in advance.

**Solution**

I was trying to get number `5` when printing `serialized`. But it is not correct. The most adequate is to do something like this:

```
u_int32_t answer;
memcpy(&answer, serialized, sizeof(u_int32_t));
std::cout << "Answer: <" << answer << ">\n";
```

Thanks for answers and comments!

Comment: This invokes undefined behavior regardless on the second print, as there is no terminator specified. Regardless, a pointer to `uint8_t` is handled synonymous (more or less) to a *string* when sent via formatted inserter to a `std::ostream&`. What were you expecting to see by sending `serialized` to `std::cout` in the first output?  Your question should include your *expected* output, and reason for those expectaions. Running a debugger you can see the memory behind that pointer, and in so doing, consider what transpires when you send it to an output stream that thinks it is a *string*.

Comment: In case you wan to answer your question, it's better to add it as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`5` in ASCII is not printable since it's a control character. [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

You can try below and it will print `a` as expected.

```
OID = (u_int32_t)'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I was trying to get number `5` when printing `serialized`. But it is not correct. The most adequate is to do something like this:

```
u_int32_t answer;
memcpy(&answer, serialized, sizeof(u_int32_t));
std::cout << "Answer: <" << answer << ">\n";
```

Thanks for answers and comments!